# Referencing user inputted numerics from one class to another in Java

Tags: java, object

The references I have created in my TestQuadraticEquations class result in null values, so when I attempt to send them to the other class I've created the program doesn't have any values to assign the variables.

The print statement for the variable was just to test if anything was being assigned in, unfortunately, nothing was. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
public class TestQuadraticEquation {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    TestQuadraticEquation nums = new TestQuadraticEquation();
    nums.promptForNum();
    TestQuadraticEquation getCo = new TestQuadraticEquation();
    int a1 = getCo.getA();
    int b1 = getCo.getB();
    int c1 = getCo.getC();
    System.out.println(a1 + " " + b1 + " " + c1);
    Equation solution1 = new Equation();
    System.out.println("For: " + solution1.getA2() + "x\u00B2 + " + 
            solution1.getB2() + "x + " + solution1.getC2());
    if (solution1.getDiscriminant() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Roots are: " + solution1.getRoot1() + " " + 
                solution1.getRoot2());
    }
    else if (solution1.getDiscriminant() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Roots are: " + solution1.getRoot1());
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No roots.");
    }  
}
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;
public void promptForNum() {
    System.out.println("Enter three coefficicents: ");
    a = in.nextInt();
    b = in.nextInt();
    c = in.nextInt();
}
public int getA() {
    return a;
}
public int getB() {
    return b;
}
public int getC() {
    return c;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the fact that the instance of `TestQuadraticEquation` called `nums` is different from the instance of `TestQuadraticEquation` called `getCo`. Therefore, when you call `nums.promptForNum()`, you are inserting values into the private variables inside the instance 'nums'.

If instead of grabbing the values of `getCo`, which are all 0, you grabbed the values of `nums`, you would get the values you were looking for.

```
int a1 = nums.getA();
int b1 = nums.getB();
int c1 = nums.getC();
System.out.println(a1 + " " + b1 + " " + c1);
```